# Convering jCard (json) to CNContact

Tags: ios, objective-c, vcf-vcard

I have jCard (VCard in json format) which is returned from server as text, and I need to parse it and convert it into CNContact object.

I have used this code but it is not working with jCard

```
NSData *vcardData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:text options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
CNContact *contact = [[CNContactVCardSerialization contactsWithData:vcardData error:nil] firstObject];
```

Comment: Which framework do you use?

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov ContactsUI

Comment: I don't find any indication of support for jcard in the apple docs.  Do you?  If not, convert the jcard to vcard, then to NSData.

Comment: You may have to it yourself (transform JCard into VCard), here are the rules: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7095#section-4

Comment: To a good JSON-vCard, see the simplest and reliable parser at http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/P2t2P/

Comment: @PeterKrauss how would you use that code in an iOS app?

Comment: @TomHarrington is an illustration of an algorithm, it is easy to translate few JS lines into Objective-C.. [jCard algorithms are not the best thing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41527663/287948).